# Toss two coins until two Heads and two Tails come up

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You play a game where you toss two fair coins in the air. You always win $1. However, if you have tossed 2 heads at least once, and 2 tails at least once, you surrender all winnings, and cannot play again. You may stop playing at anytime. What’s your strategy?

My thoughts were that this seems similar to the coupon collector. We have two bad events (2H and 2T). So after the occurence of the first bad event the second one will occur in an expected number of 4 turns. So my strategy is to stop after 3 tosses from the moment the first bad event occured.
However, I can't prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the first bad event one has $x\geq1$ dollars in the pocket. The question is whether one shall go on playing. Denote by $E(x)$ the expected total win under the best strategy in this situation. If we decide to quit we have won $x$, and if we make a next turn we have (with probability ${3\over4}$) won $x+1$  and the possibility of further play, or (with probability ${1\over4}$) we have won $0$. This shows that
$$E(x)=\max\left\{x, \ {3\over4}E(x+1)\right\}\ .\tag{1}$$
I'm assuming (without proof) that there will be an $n$ where we definitely won't play once more; hence $E(n)=n$. From this and $(1)$  we get
$$E(n-1)=\max\left\{n-1,\ {3\over4}n\right\}=n-1\qquad(n\geq4)\ .$$
By downwards induction it follows that
$$E(n)=n\qquad(n\geq 3)\ .$$
Using $(1)$ one then computes
$$E(2)=\max\left\{2,\ {3\over4}E(3)\right\}={9\over4}\ ,\qquad E(1)=\max\left\{1,\ {3\over4}E(2)\right\}={27\over16}\ .$$
This means that one should play on when $1\leq x\leq2$, and quit otherwise.

Comment: If one would ask: what is the expected value of the game? would that be $\frac{27}{16}$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have won $\$x$ by the first bad event, and plan to continue for $y$ more rounds.  Then your expected winnings are $$\left(\frac34\right)^y(x+y)$$
For each value of $x$, write down the winnings for the various $y$, and pick the best $y$ for each $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of flips until first bad flip/failure (HH or TT) is 2.

So we would have 2 dollars at this point on an average.

Now, E(next roll with one failure)= 3/4*(2 + 1) => 9/4= 2.25, so we would roll again as it is greater than 2 dollars.

If we get a success, for next roll the expected value is 3/4*(3 + 1) => 3 which is equal to the current amount in hand so I would stop if I have 3 dollars with one failure.

In case, we do not have any failures until 3 dollars, as soon as we see the first failure we should stop.

Comment: This is the most concise answer to this question with a simple logical proof.

Answer (score 0):

Each turn after the first bad event, you win another dollar with probability $\frac{3}{4}$ and loss everything with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus, assuming the first bad event happened at turn $m$, then at the $n$th turn after the bad event you have a $(\frac{3}{4})^n$ probability of earning $n$ dollars beyond the initial $m$, and $1 - (\frac{3}{4})^n$ probability of earning nothing. So in general you have an expected win of $(m + n)(\frac{3}{4})^n$ dollars. For $n = 0$ this is $m$, for $n = 1$ this is $(m + 1)\frac{3}{4}$, and for $n = 2$ this is $(m + 2)\frac{9}{16}$, for $n = 3$ this is $(m + 3)\frac{27}{64}$.

$m \leq (m + 1)\frac{3}{4} \iff m \leq 3$

$(m + 1)\frac{3}{4} \leq (m + 2)\frac{9}{16} \iff 4m + 4 \leq 3m + 6 \iff m \leq 2$

And in general,

$(m + n)(\frac{3}{4})^n \leq (m + n + 1)(\frac{3}{4})^{n + 1} \iff 4m + 4n \leq 3m + 3n + 3 \iff m \leq 3 - n \iff n \leq 3- m$

You can see that the optimal $n$ is then $\max(0, 3 - m)$